# SecurityException ReflectionPermission: Automapper

Tags: security, model-view-controller, automapper, web-hosting

I'm getting the following error using a shared Web Hosting:

```
"System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed."
```

I think that this should be related to [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper). How can I solve this?

Following the Stack Trace:

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +31
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
   System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.PerformSecurityCheck(Type owner, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean skipVisibility) +9453167
   System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor(String name, Type returnType, Type[] parameterTypes, Type owner, Boolean skipVisibility) +40
   AutoMapper.DelegateFactory.CreateDynamicMethod(MemberInfo member, Type sourceType) +291
   AutoMapper.DelegateFactory.CreateSet(PropertyInfo property) +52
   AutoMapper.Internal.PropertyAccessor..ctor(PropertyInfo propertyInfo) +64
   AutoMapper.ReflectionHelper.ToMemberAccessor(MemberInfo accessorCandidate) +209
   AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory.CreateTypeMap(Type sourceType, Type destinationType, IMappingOptions options) +256
   AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.CreateTypeMap(Type source, Type destination, String profileName) +83
   AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.CreateMap(String profileName) +92
   AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.CreateMap() +53
   AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap() +76
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line to Web.Config and it's solved.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkscy493.aspx

```
<trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
```